# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/ch3/dataBean/Edit.jsp] at line [23]

Tags: java, jquery, html

I don't understand why I'm getting the error. I'm going to assume this is error probably has occurred on other JSP, but once I get help with this I can figure the rest out.

```java
import ch2.servletController. * ;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException,
    IOException {
        RequestData data = new RequestData();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("refData", data);
        data.setData(request.getParameter("Data"));
        data.setData2(request.getParameter("Data2"));

        String address;
        if (request.getParameter("processButton") != null) {
            address = "Process.jsp";
        }
        else if (request.getParameter("submitButton") != null) {
            address = "Confirm.jsp";
        }
        else {
            address = "Edit.jsp";
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}

package ch3.dataBean;

/**
  *
  * @author Alex
*/
public class RequestData {
    protected String Data;
    protected String Data2;

    public RequestData() {}

    public void setData(String Data) {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return Data;
    }

    public void setData2(String Data2) {
        this.Data2 = Data2;
    }

    public String getData2() {
        return Data2;
    }
}
```

---

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <meta charset=?utf-8?>
  <title> Simple Form </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Please enter valid data and data2 to submit.
    <form Controller="/ch3/dataBean/Controller">
      <p> The data was received as: <strong>${param.Data}</strong>   
      <p> The data2 was received as: <strong>${param.Data2}</strong>

      <input type="text" name="Data" value="${refData.Data};">
      <input type="text" name="Data2" value="${refData.Data2};"> 
      <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit"> 
     </form>
   </body>

</html>
```

Below I have added a snip of the error stack to provide more details. I'm guessing the issue is the name of the string Data and Data2, but I'm not entirely sure

[error stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pea9z.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The cause of the error is the names you have chosen for your bean's properties. You should change the names Data and Data2 to data and data2. That way you will conform to the standards. See chapter 8 at  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf
You need to use

`protected String data;
protected String data2;`

and change the setters and getters like shown in the specification.

```
public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
} 

public void setData2(String data2) {
    this.data2 = data2;
}

public String getData2() {
    return data2;
}
```

in your JSP use

```
value="${refData.data}"
```